# Prove $a = b = 0$ in order to prove continuity on $x=0$

Tags: calculus, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

I have a mathematical problem with several parts, regarding the same function. Sometimes I have to prove continuity and sometimes to classify discontinuities.

I'll focus on the first section (Continuity on $x=0$) since it's virtually the same afterwards. The only limitation I have is that L'hopital's rule is not allowed to be used so no differentiation is allowed and everything is to be proved by the limits-methods. My calculations almost got me to the end but I feel like I'm missing 1 step before I solve it by myself, so I'd like your help.

Let there be a function $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
(1+ax+bx^2)^\frac{1}{sinx} & x>0\\ 
e^b & x=0\\ 
\frac{e^x-c}{sin(x)} & x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

We should find $a,b,c \in\mathbb{R}$ for which $f$ is continuous, meaning :
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{f(x)} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{f(x)} \in \mathbb{R}$$

1. For starters I claimed $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{f(x)}\in \mathbb{R}$ - therefore:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\Big({\frac{e^x-c}{sin(x)}\Big)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{e^x-c}{sin(x)}} \times\frac{x}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{e^x-c}{x} \times \Big(\frac{sin(x)}{x}}\Big)^{-1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{e^x-c}{x}}$$

Since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{e^x-c}{x}} \in\mathbb{R}$$
For any $c \neq 1$ the limit goes to $\infty$ Therefore **$c=1$**

2. We claim continuity, therefore: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}{f(x)} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{f(x)}$$
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{(1+ax+bx^2)^{{sinx}^{-1}}} = e^b$$
   I manipulated the power since : $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{sinx}{x}} = 1$ (this one is given)
   $$\frac{1}{sinx} =\frac{1}{sinx}\times\frac{x}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\times\Big(\frac{sinx}{x}\Big)^{-1} =  \frac{1}{x}$$
   Therefore:
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}{(1+ax+bx^2)^{{sinx}^{-1}}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\Big(1+x(a+bx)\Big)^{\frac{1}{x}}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{e^{a+bx}} = e^a$$
   I used Euler's number above: $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}{(1 +t)^\frac{1}{t}} = e$

From continuity I calim that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} = f(0)  \rightarrow e^a = e^b \rightarrow a=b$$

3. Now this is the part where I'm stuck. I somehow need to prove that $a=b=0$ but I couldn't find any. Since im 90% through I'd like to be pointed what I'm missing in order to solve this.

Comment: We have by your work $$\lim_{x\uparrow0}f(x)=1$$ So by continuity $f(0)=1$. So $e^b=1$ and thus $b=0$. Now try showing $a=0$

Comment: my question is equal to asking how can I show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}{f(x)} = 1$. For now all I can say is that it's a finite number

Comment: It is $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\exp(x)-1}x$$ which is a very well known limit: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Exponential_at_Zero

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

since we couldn't have used differentiation this question was insolvable.
we had to show that:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{(e^x - 1)}{x}} = 1$$
since it's the very definition of the derivative of $e^x$:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{(e^x - 1)}{x}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{(e^x - e^0)}{x-0}} = \frac{d}{dx}{e^x} = e^x_{(x=0)} = 1$$

Thank you all.

Comment: You can find that limit without differentiating, depending on how $x \mapsto e^x$ is defined for you. Power series, for example.

Comment: Note that it has to be possible without differentiation a proof of $\exp'=\exp$ can't use this result a priori. See for example here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Exponential_at_Zero/Proof_2 Or, as @PatrickStevens has said, just use the power series and some sort of Fubini-Tonelli